# Can't Install Windows Azure SDK November 2011 Release

Tags: windows, sdk, azure

I get this in my error log after the Web Installer fails to install the Windows Azure SDK:

```
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:35]: Burn v3.6.2228.0, path: C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2010\580DFFB79499C7427AD38C84E632FFFF39C3FBCC\WindowsAzureTools.VS1007.exe, cmdline: '/quiet /norestart /log C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsInstall.txt -burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{295A073A-499D-4CF5-B102-833C120F4671} {14075DDC-1FFC-4919-BEE8-AD508F4B7C83} 2676'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:35]: Initializing string variable 'ProductShortName' to value 'Windows Azure Tools - November 2011'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:35]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - November 2011'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:35]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsInstall.txt'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:36]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2010\580DFFB79499C7427AD38C84E632FFFF39C3FBCC\WindowsAzureTools.VS1007.exe'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Detect 2 packages
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 0
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to true.
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 0
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to true.
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 1
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Registry value not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VWDExpress\10.0', Value = 'InstallDir'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: File not found. Path = '\VWDExpress.exe'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Setting numeric variable 'VWDEXPRESS_IDE_FILE' to value 0
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Setting numeric variable 'VSDEVENV' to value 1
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Detected package: CctSetup.Shared, state: Absent, cached: No
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Detected package: CctSetup, state: Absent, cached: Yes
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Plan 2 packages, action: Install
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Condition '(VSDEVENV AND DEVENV_PROPLUS) OR VWDEXPRESS_IDE_FILE' evaluates to true.
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_CctSetup.Shared' to value 'C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsInstall_0_CctSetup.Shared.txt'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_CctSetup.Shared' to value 'C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsInstall_0_CctSetup.Shared_rollback.txt'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Planned package: CctSetup.Shared, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_CctSetup' to value 'C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsInstall_1_CctSetup.txt'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_CctSetup' to value 'C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsInstall_1_CctSetup_rollback.txt'
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Planned package: CctSetup, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Apply begin
[0A74:0A78][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Temp\{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}\.be\WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}\WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe'
[0A74:0A78][2012-03-02T10:43:37]: Registering bundle dependency key: {3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}, version 1.6.41103.1601
[0A74:0B80][2012-03-02T10:43:38]: Moving payload from working path 'C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Local\Temp\{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}\CctSetup.Shared' to path 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{10EC9A93-A581-4063-A051-0F66D47EBC92}v1.6.41103.1601\WindowsAzureTools.VSCore.VS100.en-us.msi'
[0A74:0A78][2012-03-02T10:43:38]: Applying package: CctSetup.Shared, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{10EC9A93-A581-4063-A051-0F66D47EBC92}v1.6.41103.1601\WindowsAzureTools.VSCore.VS100.en-us.msi, arguments: ' IGNOREDEPENDENCIES="{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}"'
[0A74:0A78][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[0A74:0A78][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0A74:0A78][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Removing cached package: {10EC9A93-A581-4063-A051-0F66D47EBC92}v1.6.41103.1601, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{10EC9A93-A581-4063-A051-0F66D47EBC92}v1.6.41103.1601\
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute apply.
[0A74:0A78][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Removing bundle dependency key: {3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}
[0A74:0A78][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Removing cached bundle: {3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}\
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643 restart: No
[0B88:0B9C][2012-03-02T10:43:41]: Shutting down, exit code: 0x80070643
```

Is there anything anyone can see I need to do, or could do, without having to go through the whole VS2010 Ultimate install process.  I am also using Windows 7N (with SP1).

I've just reformatted my machine and started to install all the apps and ran into this problem.

Comment: Ok I have just tried to go through the manual installation process via this link:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28045

and get this error now:

"a network error occurred while attempting to read from the file:
c:\users\downloads\windowsAzureSDK-x862.msi"

very frustrating !

Answer (score 2):

[Sorry for my English]

I had this situation too. Simplest solution is to turn on (has been turned off) Web Developer component in VS. After that Cloud  project template appeared.

Slava V.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have VS Pro installed or just VS Express?

Note that because the Azure SDK contains VS add-ins, it requires you to have VS Pro or above, or VS Web Developer Express installed. From Step 1 in the installation instructions:

1. Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional or above OR Install Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

HTH